# Whenever I try to run Tomcat with Jersey, it refuses to load

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

Basically I am trying to create a simple Hello World program using Rational Software Architect. To create the server I use Tomcat and Jersey. I found that when I create the server without putting the jersey jar files into WEB-INF/lib but rather I create a custom user library with all the jar files, Tomcat will compile fine but the url will not load the "Hello World" text, just a 404 error. I simple do http://localhost:8080/*project name*/rest/*class path name* and nothing will come up. I think its because I don't have the jersey files in WEB-INF/lib but when I put the jersey jar files in that folder and try to run the tomcat server, i get a "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start." error.

Please help me out and thanks in advance.

```
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule       begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:RestHello' did not find a matching property.
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 7 2015 17:14:55 UTC
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.62.0
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1 build 7601 Service Pack 1
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\SDP80x\jdk\jre
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           jvmwi3260sr9-20110324_78506
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            IBM Corporation
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\EzraZWS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\RESTWS\Tomcat 7.0
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xjcl:jclscar_24
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path=C:\SDP80x\jdk\jre\bin
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dsun.boot.library.path=C:\SDP80x\jdk\jre\bin
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.library.path=C:\SDP80x\jdk\jre\bin;.;C:/SDP80x/jdk/jre/bin/j9vm;C:/SDP80x/jdk/jre/bin;C:/SDP80x/jdk/jre/lib/i386;c:\eip40\tibco\tibrv\8.4\bin;C:\eip40\tibco\tibrv\8.3\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\RationalSDLC\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Encryption\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\SDP80x\jdk\bin;;C:\SDP80x;
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.home=C:\SDP80x\jdk\jre
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.ext.dirs=C:\SDP80x\jdk\jre\lib\ext
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Duser.dir=C:\SDP80x
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: _j2se_j9=71168
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xdump
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.class.path=c:\eip40\tibco\tibrv\8.4\lib\tibrvnative.jar;C:\eip40\tibco\tibrv\8.3\lib\tibrvnative.jar;C:\SDP80x\jdk\bin;
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\EzraZWS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\RESTWS\Tomcat 7.0
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\EzraZWS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\RESTWS\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.class.path=C:\RESTWS\Tomcat 7.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\RESTWS\Tomcat 7.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\SDP80x\jdk\lib\tools.jar;C:\EzraZWS\RestHello\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-client.jar;C:\EzraZWS\RestHello\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-common.jar;C:\EzraZWS\RestHello\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-container-servlet.jar;C:\EzraZWS\RestHello\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-container-servlet-core.jar;C:\EzraZWS\RestHello\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-media-jaxb.jar;C:\EzraZWS\RestHello\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jersey-server.jar
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dsun.java.command=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dsun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: _port_library
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: _org.apache.harmony.vmi.portlib
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\SDP80x\jdk\jre\bin;.;C:/SDP80x/jdk/jre/bin/j9vm;C:/SDP80x/jdk/jre/bin;C:/SDP80x/jdk/jre/lib/i386;c:\eip40\tibco\tibrv\8.4\bin;C:\eip40\tibco\tibrv\8.3\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\RationalSDLC\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Encryption\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\SDP80x\jdk\bin;;C:\SDP80x;
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 559 ms
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
Throwable occurred: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1038)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:429)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:645)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
Throwable occurred: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RestHello]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RestHello]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer, offset=6 (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2961)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
Throwable occurred: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
Throwable occurred: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 10, 2015 12:56:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

My code:

```
package RestHello;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path ("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

and my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>RestHello</display-name>
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
                <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>RestHello</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unsupported class version error suggests that you are using a newer version of jersey than is supported by your tomcat installation. Most likely it is because of jre version mismatch - the jersey library you are using requires a newer jre but you have an older version

Comment: That makes sense. I installed the latest jersey (2.17) but I only have tomcat 7, the latest is 8. However, this is because my version of rational doesn't have the option to select tomcat 8 as a server, only Tomcat 7. So is it possible to match the jre without having to install the newest tomcat? Or is there some sort of workaround?

Comment: Use an earlier version of jersey that tomcat 7 can handle?

Comment: I switched to jersey 1.19 and put the jersey 1.19 jar bundle file into web-inf/lib. Now the server starts but I still get no response with my url. My code and web.xml is in the above question section.

Comment: I believe the servlet container name changed between 1.* & 2.* of jersey. It wasn't org.glassfish...... earlier but com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer. There were other changes in parameters as well between these two versions so I suggest you go through the 1.19 docs as well.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it. Thanks Sasikanth you were right about my error. The jre must match for apache, your project, and Jersey. The newest Jersey uses jre7 so when you install apache, use jre7 as the build path. Also my Rational project was defaulted to java 1.6 not 1.7. So you have to manually create a build path to jre7. This video teaches you how to do that (just go to java build path in properties of your project, double click jre system library, click installed jres, then add a new path to your jre directory). To find the jre directory just look up java on the start menu, click the java tab, then click view. This made my project build path jre7, tomcat should already be jre7 from the install, and jersey is jre7 as well so everything will match and your server will run correctly.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whQaqnI4SrU